# How do I create a python exe app that use playwright

Tags: python, playwright

I have this app that run in terminal, now I want to compile it into an exe file. This app requires external libraries and I have to install playwright through

> pip install playwright

and

> playwright install

I tried PyInstaller

> pyinstaller --onefile main.py

but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What specifically "does not work"? Always share symptoms and error messages.

Comment: @jarmod a screen flashed for a second and turn off

Comment: what sort of screen? a terminal? probably a terminal that then had an error message and then the terminal closed. You should set up a logger so that you can, well, log the error message. Or, another silly technique I've used that has worked - use something like Open Broadcaster Software to record your screen when you run it, then look at the video and free-frame when you can actually read the error message. Logging is better than that, because it may well break multiple times (and also logging is good)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This guide explains how to create an .exe file using Playwright https://medium.com/@animeshsingh161/how-to-convert-a-python-playwright-script-into-an-executable-app-playwright-with-python-b61d8ff0ca64 using an venv; however, as a Windows user is important to add the keyword set on the terminal on step 3 (set PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0 playwright install browser), where browser is the browser that you are using, for example, set PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0 playwright install firefox. The browser is optional, but, if you type it, it is going to save you space.

Hope this helps